# how to pass function through previous function? python

Tags: python, testing, iteration

The goal of this program is to test and see if there is three or more blues/'b'. How would I go about doing this? Any help always appreciated, thanks.

```
def manufactoria():

    test(three_or_more_blues, "brrrrrbrrrrrb")

def test(fn, string):

    if fn(string):
        result = "accepted"
    else:
        result = "not accepted"

    print('The string "' + string + '" is ' + result)

manufactoria()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: `string.count('b') >= 3`

Comment: A tedious way of doing this is using a for loop

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to pass a function as an argument to another function. You can either use that function itself

```
def test(string):
    if string.count('b') > 3:
        #do stuff
    else:
        #do other stuff

test("brrrbbrb")
```

or, you can define another function, and just call it from within that function

```
def test(string):
    if checker(string):
        #do stuff
    else:
        #do stuff

def checker(string):
    if string.count('b') > 3:
        #return True
    else:
        #return False

test("bbbrrbbbr")
```